# Is there a keybind that can place a caret at the next instance of a matching word in Visual Studio 2022 like in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have my caret at an instance of a word. I want to press a keyboard shortcut and have a caret be added to the next occurrence of that word. Is that possible in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: By "caret" do you mean the `^` character? Or your text editor's cursor location?

Comment: I mean cursor instance. Sublime always called it multi-caret, so that stuck with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret` keybinding, which by default is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

[image: edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret keybinding in settings]

In this example .gif, each time I perform the keybind with my cursor (caret) *anywhere* within the first instance of the word "Test", it places another cursor/caret at the end of the next instance of the word, and also highlights it.  This allows you to bulk edit/rename a word.

[image: caret keybinding gif example]